# Contour/curve with orientation

Tags: matplotlib, plot, orientation, curve

How would I plot a curve (in 3d perhaps) with something to show the direction that it's going. For example, to show that a circular plane curve is going clockwise or counterclockwise.

A curve like the one here,
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html

I am not sure even if there is a comparable function right now, so I don't have an example to show you.
Thanks for reading.

Edit: I search quite a bit on this, don't think you can do this on gnuplot either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib curve with arrow ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911898/matplotlib-curve-with-arrow-ticks)

Comment: The other one requires some changes for this application. This one applies for parametric curves generally. Thanks for your attention here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I have no time for more than a quick and dirty hack, so here we go (liberally inspired from the code in mpl `streamplot`)

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def add_arrow_to_line2D(
    axes, line, arrow_locs=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8],
    arrowstyle='-|>', arrowsize=1, transform=None):
    """
    Add arrows to a matplotlib.lines.Line2D at selected locations.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    axes: 
    line: list of 1 Line2D obbject as returned by plot command
    arrow_locs: list of locations where to insert arrows, % of total length
    arrowstyle: style of the arrow
    arrowsize: size of the arrow
    transform: a matplotlib transform instance, default to data coordinates

    Returns:
    --------
    arrows: list of arrows
    """
    if (not(isinstance(line, list)) or not(isinstance(line[0], 
                                           mlines.Line2D))):
        raise ValueError("expected a matplotlib.lines.Line2D object")
    x, y = line[0].get_xdata(), line[0].get_ydata()

    arrow_kw = dict(arrowstyle=arrowstyle, mutation_scale=10 * arrowsize)
    if transform is None:
        transform = axes.transData

    arrows = []
    for loc in arrow_locs:
        s = np.cumsum(np.sqrt(np.diff(x) ** 2 + np.diff(y) ** 2))
        n = np.searchsorted(s, s[-1] * loc)
        arrow_tail = (x[n], y[n])
        arrow_head = (np.mean(x[n:n + 2]), np.mean(y[n:n + 2]))
        p = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch(
            arrow_tail, arrow_head, transform=transform,
            **arrow_kw)
        axes.add_patch(p)
        arrows.append(p)
    return arrows


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
t = np.linspace(0., 4*np.pi, 100.)
line = ax.plot(np.log(t+1)*np.cos(t), np.log(t+1)*np.sin(t),"-")
add_arrow_to_line2D(ax, line, arrow_locs=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.99],
                    arrowsize=1.5)

ax.axis("equal")
ax.set_xlim([-4., 4.])
ax.set_ylim([-4., 4.])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful, thanks a lot. For plotting multiple lines, I'd recommend adding `line_color = line[0].get_color()` and setting some combination of `color`, `edgecolor`, and `facecolor` to `line_color` in your `arrow_kw`